# xk6-browser client-side test result for single user one iteration is not correct

Tags: k6, xk6-browser

I have just started using xk6-browser, and executed following test script.

```
import { chromium } from 'k6/x/browser';

export default function () {
  const browser = chromium.launch({ headless: false });
  const page = browser.newPage();

  page
    .goto('https://test.k6.io/', { waitUntil: 'networkidle' })
    .then(() => {
      page.screenshot({ path: 'screenshot.png' });
    })
    .finally(() => {
      page.close();
      browser.close();
    });
}
```

with the following command `./xk6-browser run k6-browser-testing-example.js`

I got the following test results.

[image]

The test was executed with 1 virtual user and for one iteration.
Why am I getting different average, min and max values for `browser_dom_content_loaded`?

Comment: The page loads 3 external resources, perhaps those are registered as a DOM load event too? (I'm guessing here). Can you try with `http://www.example.com`?

Comment: Average, max etc., were different for `browser_dom_content_loaded` and `browser_loaded`, even for `http://www.example.com`.

Comment: Apparently, there is a bug.  https://github.com/grafana/xk6-browser/issues/518

Comment: You can post the bug as a self-answer (quoting the important parts and proper reference of the source).

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, there is a known bug at the time of the testing.

[Issue #518](https://github.com/grafana/xk6-browser/issues/518)